# AngularJS v1 material md-subheader bounces badly when scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Hi All fellow programmers and geniuses,

I am using md-subheader of angularmaterial v1 demo at:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/subheader

I am building a page in mobile device using this and the problem is that the subheader bounces badly when it should not move a bit. This problem was addressed already in the link below (with proper demo) but I could not find any solution.

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5862

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after searching for a while, I had to abandon `md-subheader` and instead I put a div above an `md-content` that would act as a stationary header when the `md-content` scrolled. Then I conditionally applied a style to the div that would bump it over the width of a scrollbar if there was enough content to scroll so the header would line up with the content.

I did that by defining this style:

```
.invisible-scrollbar {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: white;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: white;
    scrollbar-base-color: white;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: white;
    scrollbar-face-color: white;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: white;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: white;
}
.invisible-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And then applying it to the header div with this:

```
ng-class="{'invisible-scrollbar':vm.resultsCanScroll}"
```

And finally, I check if the content has a scrollbar in the controller which was a little tricky with an `md-virtual-repeat`:

```
// Wait until the next digest so the content is bound before checking the scroll height.
$timeout(function () {
    var scroller = angular.element('#searchResultList .md-virtual-repeat-scroller');
    vm.resultsCanScroll = scroller[0].scrollHeight > scroller.height();
});
```

Of course this won't help you if you have multiple `md-subheader` tags, but it depends what you're trying to do.